# Bloomberg API v3: Querying by ISIN (or CUSIP)

Tags: c#, bloomberg

The problem: I am given a list of ISINs for a variety of instruments of unspecified type.  In the Bloomberg Excel API, this presents no problem; I can put in, say, =BDP("CA5054401156 ISIN", "NAME"), and get my answer.  But that doesn't work in a C# program using the Bloomberg API V3.  Using

```
request.GetElement("securities").AppendValue("CA5054401156 Equity");
```

does work, but that's no help when I don't know if the instrument is an equity. Is there a way of specifying securities by ISIN without knowing the instrument type?

Answer (score 11):

Found the answer:

```
request.GetElement("securities").AppendValue("/isin/CA5054401156");
```

Comment: If this is the solution (which I think it is), you should accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

Note that in .NET and Python using `blpapi` you can do:

> request.getElement("securities").appendValue("/isin/CA5054401156");

or

> request.append("securities", "/isin/CA5054401156")